# Posting Tweets from Iphone App

Tags: iphone, twitter

My app has three text fields:
1) Username

```
    // Initialization code
    usernameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5, 280, 30)];//usernameTextField released

    usernameTextField.placeholder = @"Username";
    usernameTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    //Username text field
    usernameTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    usernameTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    usernameTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    usernameTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    usernameTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
```

2) Password

```
    // Initialization code
    passwordTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 90, 280, 30)]; 
    passwordTextField.placeholder = @"Password";
    passwordTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    //Password text field
    passwordTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    passwordTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    passwordTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    passwordTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
    passwordTextField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    passwordTextField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

3) Text View

```
    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 310, 180)]; 
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0f];
```

What is the best/quick way to use these to upload tweets to twitter directly, with the login details for the first two and the Tweet being the textView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [MGTwitterEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/02/22/mgtwitterengine-twitter-from-cocoa).  It provides everything you need

Authenticating is as easy as

```
MGTwitterEngine *twitterEngine = [[MGTwitterEngine alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[twitterEngine setUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
```

and then you just use

```
- (NSString *)sendUpdate:(NSString *)status;
```

to post an update

Comment: You might also want to check out the code that Ben Gottlieb has on Github to handle the newer OAuth authentication that Twitter is moving to: http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone